# Rust Actix-Web v4 creating a response with custom header

Tags: rust, http-headers, actix-web

I am trying to create a response inside a handler with actix-web v4.

The `header` method has changed to `append_header` which now instead of a key value pair takes a header object.

The original documentation [here](https://actix.rs/docs/response/) gives the following example:

```
use actix_web::HttpResponse;

async fn index() -> HttpResponse {
    HttpResponse::Ok()
        .content_type("plain/text")
        .header("X-Hdr", "sample")
        .body("data")
}
```

I can create a header with `append_header(ContentType::plaintext())` with a predefined mime name, but I haven't found any way to create a custom type.

I would have expected something like `Header::from("'X-Hdr': 'sample'")` to work but haven't found any way to create this header.

What would be the right way to create the `'X-Hdr':'sample'` header in actix-web v4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```rust
pub fn append_header<H>(&mut self, header: H) -> &mut Self where
    H: IntoHeaderPair,
```

The `append_header` method takes any type implementing [`IntoHeaderPair`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/4.0.0-beta.6/actix_web/http/header/trait.IntoHeaderPair.html). If you look at the documentation for the trait you will see that it is implemented for:

```rust
(&'_ HeaderName, V)
(&'_ str, V)
(HeaderName, V)
(&'_ [u8], V)
(String, V)
```

`V` is any type implementing [`IntoHeaderValue`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/4.0.0-beta.6/actix_web/http/header/trait.IntoHeaderValue.html), which includes `String`, `&str`, `Vec`, and integer types.

Therefore you can simply write `.append_header(("X-Hdr", "sample"))`

Comment: Thanks, if I wanted to implement this trait on my type, say a single `&str "'X-Hdr':'sample'"`, how would I do this?

Comment: You would create a wrapper type and implement the `try_into_header_pair` method by splitting on a colon.

Comment: I don't see why you would want to do this though.

Comment: While it does not really serve a purpose, I need to get a better understanding of how traits work. I had reviewed the source code and saw the implementation, but was unable to interpret it correctly. So TLDR; simple as an exercise ;-) Thanks again for the help.